# Elementary problem with integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can someone give me a clue? 
Prove that there are no integers $x, y$ such that $x^2 + 3y^2 = 92$.

Comment: One can always test $y=0$ to $5$, since $6$ is obviously too big.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** What are the squares modulo $3$?

Answer (score 0):

As said by others, mod $3$ or brute force solve it easily. Here's another way:

$92=23\cdot 2^2$. If $23\mid x,y$, we get a contradiction ($23^2\mid x^2+y^2=23\cdot 2^2$).

If $23\nmid x,y$, then $23\mid 92=x^2+3y^2\implies x^2\equiv -3y^2\pmod{23}$

$\iff \left(xy^{-1}\right)^2\equiv -3\pmod{23}$. But $-3$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ iff $p\equiv \{0,1\}\pmod{3}$ (see [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity)); and $23\equiv 2\not\equiv \{0,1\}\pmod{3}$. Contradiction. No solutions exist.